# powershell get-distributiongroupmember

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to get all members of a distribution group in office365 that are in two groups one. The first group "Precon" filters users that are in a specific group. The next group "Office" gets the office distribution group that the memebers are in. The end goal is that I would like to get the office location for each member in the precon group.

I have tried a couple of things but dont know if I have the correct syntax or if what I was trying even works the way I think it does.

So far this is what I have

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

$groupmembers = foreach($g in Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {name -like "Precon"}) {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $g.SamAccountName | select Name   
}

$office = foreach($o in Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {name -like "*Office"}) 
{
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $o.SamAccountName | select Name   
}

$match = $groupmembers |  ForEach {
    if ($_ -imatch $office){
      Write-Output $_ "matches"
    }
}

$match
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for one: change `select Name`   to `select -Expand Name`. That will get you cleaner output to compare.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output?

For the last block of code I'd look at:

```
$match = $groupmembers |  where $office -contains $_

$match
```

Comment: This output  returns the full list of members not just the one in the Precon group

Comment: That is likely down to `if ($_ -imatch $office){`
The -imatch does a case insensitive regular expression match against `$_` using `$office` (which will be a string or an array) as the regular expression. What does the code I suggested provide as the output?

Comment: I get no results when I run:                                                      $groupmembers = foreach($g in Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {name -like "Precon"}) {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $g.SamAccountName | select -Expand Name   
}

$office = foreach($o in Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {name -like "*Office"}) 
{
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $o.SamAccountName | select -Expand Name   
}

$match = $groupmembers |  ForEach {
    if ($_ -imatch $office){
      Write-Output $_ "matches"
    }
}

Comment: I know, You said that previously. What I asked is what output you get if you replace the code I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Sorry bud I didnt get to reply to your question.. I did manage to find the solution to my problem though. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that works

```
$precon = @()
foreach($i in Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {Name -like '*Precon'}) {
    $precon += ( Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $i.samAccountName | foreach {$_.Name} )
}

$office = @{}
foreach($i in Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {Name -like '*Office'}) {
    $office[$i.name] += ( Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $i.samAccountName | foreach {$_.Name} )
}

$uber = @()
foreach ($key in $office.Keys) {
    $preconOffice = $office[$key] | Where { $precon -Contains $_ }
    foreach ($name in $preconOffice) { $uber += ( New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop (@{'Office' = $key ;'Name' = $name}) ) }
}

$uber
```